# How to create Cardview with firebase getKey parameter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cardview

I try to create cardview from firebase data using listAdapter. It's work with getValue, but not work for getKey. Any one can help me......

```
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list = new ArrayList<List>();

                Iterable<DataSnapshot> itemSnapShot = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                for(DataSnapshot items : itemSnapShot)
                {
                    List products = items.getValue(List.class);
                    list.add(products);
                }
                adapter = new ListAdapter(Stock.this,list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

It works, but how to use it with getKey function in this code....

"List products = items.getValue(List.class);"

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is happening when you are using `items.getKey()`? Do you have an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you want to do, but to get key to each product you may use the `getKey()` method for this task, like this...

```
 reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapShot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                //This key string is key of a child in the database.
                String key = data.getKey(); 

                //Do what do you want here....
            }
        }
```

and for display all products from your database use this code.

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           list = new ArrayList<List>();
           for(DataSnapShot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                List products = items.getValue(List.class);
                list.add(products);
                //Do what do you want here....
            }

           adapter = new ListAdapter(Stock.this,list);
           recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Hope it will help you!